# Plugin causing JavaScript conflicts in Wordpress image slider

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a cookie warning plugin on a Wordpress site. The site theme uses a slider on the homepage, but activating the plugin breaks the slider in three ways:

1) It bumps the slider images up the page after a few seconds, obscuring the main navigation menu.

2) The transition effects disappear

3) The image captions disappear

Here's how it should look: http://www.drivestart.co.uk

And here's a mock up showing the conflicts:
http://samcampsall.co.uk/DriveStart/

I isolated a rule for the .nivoSlider class `top: -74px;` which was dragging things up, presumably after the JScript kicks in. I've I set this to 0px so when the page loads the image slider appears below where it should be and then bumps up to the 'right' space - not ideal, but liveable. However, this won't solve the other more serious issues.

I noticed that, when it does bump up, the style rule for the image caption changes from `display:block` to `display:none`. When functioning normally the JavaScript does this to hide the caption while the slides transition, but then it changes back to `display:block`. The fact that it gets stuck on `display:none` may be a clue to why the transition effects don't work either and the whole thing jumps up the page, all at the same time?

Appreciate any advice on this, I know basically zero about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your JavaScript:

> jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

```
    return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
```

It is worth fixing this error and seeing if you still have a problem.

Comment: I think this is a function created in jquery.easing.js which is a js file in the theme folder.

Comment: You need to check that the js file is definitely referenced in your page and that the reference is before this line of js.